# VS 2019 Automating Build and Test with MSBuild.exe and VSTest.console.exe

Tags: c#, msbuild, vstest

My home grown automation is as follows (I use a bash shell):

```
cd c:/tmp
rm -rf myproj
git clone <repo-url>/myproj -b releaseX
cd myproj
// Get the NuGet packages
msbuild.exe -t:restore
wait
// Build my Release Version
msbuild.exe myproj.sln -t:Rebuild -p:Configuration=Release
wait
// Run my Unit Tests that I keep in a UnitTest dir
vstest.console.exe UnitTests/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/UnitTests.dll
wait
```

Outside of having some hard coded dir names or project names, is this a valid way to automate with the VSTest environment? My goal is to implement a no frills nightly build and test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach, it will work.

My suggestions to you:

1. Based on the path to your UT binaries, you are targeting .NET Core. Instead of invoking the vstest.console.exe directly, you can call `dotnet test` on your UT projects. This would avoid having to specify the exact path to your binaries, the `dotnet` command figures out where they are.
2. Along the same vein, you can call `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` instead of the `msbuild` equivalents. There's not a huge benefit to doing that other than being more "modern".